# How to use Redis with Play 2.3.7

Tags: scala, playframework, redis

I've just enabled `Redis` by following [the official guidelines](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/redis). Everything compiles fine and `Redis` is loaded when the application first starts:

```
[info] application - Redis Plugin enabled. Connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 to 0 with timeout 2000.
[info] application - Redis Plugin pool configuration: redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig@287ab5fe[maxTotal=8,maxIdle=8,minIdle=0,lifo=true,maxWaitMillis=-1,minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000,softMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000,numTestsPerEvictionRun=-1,evictionPolicyClassName=org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.DefaultEvictionPolicy,testOnBorrow=false,testOnReturn=false,testWhileIdle=true,timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000,blockWhenExhausted=true,jmxEnabled=true,jmxNamePrefix=pool]
```

... but as soon as I try to access the cache from my application like this

```
Cache.set(id, tokenTrace, (expiration.getMillis / 1000).asInstanceOf[Int])
```

... I get the following warning:

```
[warn] application - could not deserialize key:ecbba6d3-3ef2-4bbe-a979-d0e68ffee9bd ex:redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:42)
at org.sedis.Pool.withJedisClient(sedis.scala:101)
at com.typesafe.plugin.RedisPlugin$$anon$1.get(RedisPlugin.scala:178)
at play.api.cache.Cache$.get(Cache.scala:80)
at services.auth.cache.CacheTokenTraceDaoComponent$CacheTokenTraceDao$$anonfun$remove$2.apply$mcI$sp(CacheTokenTraceDaoComponent.scala:70)
```

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**

The `TokenTrace` class just traces a JWT and looks like this:

```
class TokenTrace private(protected var json: JsValue) extends JsEntity
  with Serializable {

  def id = json as (__ \ 'id).readNullable[String]
  def id_= (v: Option[String]) = setValue((__ \ 'id), Json.toJson(v))
  def username = json as (__ \ 'username).readNullable[String]
  def username_= (v: Option[String]) = setValue((__ \ 'username), Json.toJson(v))
  def expirationTime = json as (__ \ 'expirationTime).read[DateTime]
  def expirationTime_= (v: DateTime) = setValue((__ \ 'expirationTime), Json.toJson(v))

  def copy(json: JsValue) = throw new UnsupportedOperationException
  override def toString = json.toString
}
```

Comment: Is just a class that contains token id and expiration time. The authorization system of my application is based on JWT (JSON Web Token)... and I use to store token traces (id + expiration time) in the database. Now the idea would be to cache token traces with Redis ;-)

Comment: Is that class `Serializable`? Because the plugin only supports `String`, `Int`, `Long`, `Boolean` and `Serializable`.

Comment: No, it wasn't. Anyway, just made the class `Serializable`... but the problem remains :-(

Comment: Just added to my post ;-)

Comment: Hmm.. what is `JsEntity` ? This works fine for me with it cut out.

Comment: OK, now it works. As mentioned before, I made `TokenTrace` serializable and fixed `redis.uri` in `application.conf` like this: `redis.uri = "redis://localhost:6379"` (I missed the `redis://` prefix since I read a document saying that `redis.uri = "localhost"` would be fine). Anyway, thank you very much for your valuable support.

Comment: If you want to cache with redis look at my play-redis plugin implementing redis as cache plugin https://github.com/KarelCemus/play-redis